# Covert lambda result to flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have the intention of converting the structure I am currently using to flow. It may sound silly or irrelevant to you.
Let me explain to you the structure:

- I have an object named `BleDataSource`. For example, it has a function like below.

```
    fun performConnect(device: BluetoothDevice, result: ((Resource<BleOperationResult>) -> Unit)) {
        enqueueOperation(Connect(device, result))
    }

    fun callback() {
        if ( operation is Connect ) {
           if  ( erroroccured )
               operation.result(Resource.Error("error"))
           else
               operation.result(Resource.Loading())
        }
    }

    fun onetherCallback() {
        if ( operation is Connect ) {
               operation.result(Resource.Success())
        }
    }
```

- This function saves to the job queue and connects to the device when it's turn. I can report the current status of the job(For example Loading, Success Or Error) because I also save the `result`.
- From repository i am using this function as below:

```
    override fun connect(device: BluetoothDevice, result: (Resource<BleOperationResult>) -> Unit) {
        handler.performConnect(device, result)
    }
```

But I want it to return as flow from the repository.

```
    override fun connect(device: BluetoothDevice): Flow<Resource<BleOperationResult> {
        handler.performConnect(device) {
        }
    }
```

How can I do that? (according to recommandation i can also edit the `BleDataSource` class)

EDIT:

### My queue mechanism:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
class BleDataSource  @Inject constructor(
    private val handler: Handler
) {

    private val operationQueue = ConcurrentLinkedQueue<BleOperationType>()
    private val operationLock = ReentrantLock()
    private var pendingOperation: BleOperationType? = null

    fun performConnect(device: BluetoothDevice, result: ((Resource<BleOperationResult>) -> Unit)) {
        enqueueOperation(Connect(device, result))
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun enqueueOperation(operation: BleOperationType) {
        handler.post {
            operationQueue.add(operation)
            if ( !operationLock.isLocked ) {
                doNextOperation()
            }
        }
    }


    @Synchronized
    private fun signalEndOfOperation() {
        handler.post {
            pendingOperation = null
            operationLock.unlock()
            if ( operationQueue.isNotEmpty() ) {
                doNextOperation()
            }
        }
    }


    @Synchronized
    private fun doNextOperation() {
        if ( operationLock.isLocked ) {
            Timber.i("doNextOperation already locked, returning...")
            return
        }

        val operation = operationQueue.poll() ?: run {
            Timber.v("Operation queue empty, returning...")
            return
        }
        operationLock.lock()
        pendingOperation = operation


        if ( operation is Connect ) {
            with(operation) {
                operation.result(Resource.Loading(message = "Connecting to ${device.name}"))
                bluetoothGatt = if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M ) {
                    device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback)
                } else {
                    device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)
                }
            }
        }

    }


        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            val deviceAddress = gatt.device.address
            val operation = pendingOperation
            var res: Resource<BleOperationResult> = Resource.Error(errorMessage = "Unknown Error!")

            if ( status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS ) {
                if ( newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED ) {
                    res = Resource.Loading(message = "Discovering Services")
                    gatt.discoverServices()
                } else if ( newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED ) {
                    res = Resource.Error(errorMessage = "Unexpected Disconnected")
                }
            } else {
                res = Resource.Error(errorMessage = "Error:$status encountered fro:$deviceAddress!")
            }

            if ( operation is Connect ) {
                operation.result(res)
            }
            if ( res is Resource.Error ) {
                if ( operation is Connect  ) {
                signalEndOfOperation()
                }
            }
        }


        override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
            val operation = pendingOperation
            var res: Resource<BleOperationResult> = Resource.Error(errorMessage = "Unknown Error!")

            if ( status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS ) {
              res = Resource.Success(data = BleOperationResult.ConnectionResult(profile))
                }
            } else {
                res = Resource.Error(errorMessage = "Failed to discover services...")
            }

            if ( operation is Connect ) {
                operation.result(res)
            }
            if ( pendingOperation is Connect ) {
                signalEndOfOperation()
            }
        }
```

```
abstract class BleOperationType {
    abstract val result: ((Resource<BleOperationResult>) -> Unit)
}
data class Connect(val device: BluetoothDevice,
                   override val result: ((Resource<BleOperationResult>) -> Unit)) : BleOperationType()
```

Comment: How many times does the `performConnect` function call its callback? Does it happen once or multiple times?

Comment: Also it might be useful to share a bit more about the order of events, and who calls what. For instance, who calls `callback()` and `onetherCallback()`? When? Should this affect the flow returned by `performConnect()`?

Comment: @Joffrey multiple times. i can also be called from another thread or another function.

Comment: @Joffrey this callbacks calls from bluetooth kernel. From example onConnectionStatusChanged

Comment: I think we're missing the broader context here, with the operation queue management. It's hard to tell how the events play out, and who does what. Maybe sharing a sequence diagram would help, or more code

Comment: @Joffrey i shared a litte bit code to show how i implemented queuing mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it looks like a classic case of converting a "multi-shot" callback function to a flow.

This can be done using [callbackFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html):

```kotlin
fun BleDataSource.connect(device: BluetoothDevice): Flow<Resource<BleOperationResult>> = callbackFlow {
    performConnect(device) { res ->
        val result = channel.trySend(res)

        // if the callback caller can make sense of exceptions
        result.exceptionOrNull?.let { throw it }
    }
    awaitClose()
}
```

The problem is that I don't see a way to unregister the callback from the API you provided. Once you called `performConnect` with a lambda, it looks like this lambda listener cannot be removed. If there is a way to do that, you should do it in the lambda passed to `awaitClose { ... }`.

Comment: If the operation is a success or an error, I assign that object to null and move on to the next operation( operation = null; doNextIperation()). I did not share this. Is that what you meant by removing the lambda listener?

Comment: Yes, but the point is that you should also do it if someone cancels the flow and stops listening, otherwise you're leaking this lambda. So it should be done in `awaitClose { }` too (I mean set to null the place where you store the lambda given to the `Connect` event.)

Comment: btw i guess i also need to implement corotuine for channel.send() because it doesnt allow me write like this and gives an error => Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

Comment: You can use `trySend` instead, which is not suspending, but then you should check the result and maybe do something with it. Does the callback caller handle exceptions? Backpressure?

Answer (score 1):

I might not be able to understand your problem properly but what I understood is that you have a function in data class that gives callback in repository and you want to convert it in flow.

You can simply use a callback flow and convert your callback into flow -

```
override fun connect(device: BluetoothDevice): Flow<Resource<BleOperationResult> {
    return callbackFlow {
             handler.performConnect(device) { result ->
                 trySend(result)
             }
           }
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: You have to call `awaitClose` in a `callbackFlow` block, or the flow will reach completed state immediately and throw IllegalStateException.