# Send message to callback flow from consumer

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I don't know if what I want is exactly possible but first let me share the code.
The code below simply creates a callbackflow(Producer) and sends it to the viewmodel(Consumer).

#### Resource

```
sealed class Resource<out T:Any>{
    data class Success<out T:Any> (val data:T):Resource<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception):Resource<Nothing>()
    data class Loading(val message:String):Resource<Nothing>()
}
```

#### Repository:

```
class MyRepository() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "___BBBMyRepository"
    }

    var globalJob: Job? = null
    private fun performSomething(result: ((Resource<Int>) -> Unit)) {
        globalJob = GlobalScope.launch {
            result(Resource.Loading("Loading-1"))
            delay(2500)
            result(Resource.Loading("Loading-2"))
            delay(2500)
            result(Resource.Loading("Loading-3"))
            delay(2500)
            result(Resource.Error(Exception("Try again...")))
        }
    }

    fun startPerform(): Flow<Resource<Int>> = callbackFlow {
        performSomething{ result ->
            Log.d(TAG, "performSomething $result")
            trySend(result)
        }
        awaitClose {
            globalJob?.cancel()
            Log.d(TAG, "startPerform awaitClose")
        }
    }
}
```

#### MyViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class BViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val myRepository: MyRepository
): ViewModel() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "___BBBViewModel"
    }

    init {
        Log.i(TAG, "Initialized")
        myRepository.startPerform()
            .onEach {
                Log.i(TAG, it.toString())
            }.onCompletion {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnCompletion")
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        Log.i(TAG, "OnCleared")
    }
}
```

If I come back with the back key before the flow is completed, it will trigger `awaitClose{}` and the flow will terminate successfully.

But when there is an error situation, I want to do the reproduction process according to the request from the viewmodel.

So somehow I need to send request to startPerform function from viewmodel as in awaitclose.

I want to write a code like below. Is this possible?

```
    fun startPerform(): Flow<Resource<Int>> = callbackFlow {
        performSomething{ result ->
            Log.d(TAG, "performSomething $result")
            trySend(result)
        }
        
        restartFlow { 
            
        }
        
        awaitClose {
            globalJob?.cancel()
            Log.d(TAG, "startPerform awaitClose")
        }
    }
```

```
    init {
        Log.i(TAG, "Initialized")
        myRepository.startPerform()
            .onEach {
                Log.i(TAG, it.toString())
if ( it is Resource.Error ) {//-----------------
    restartFlow //-----------------
}//-----------------
            }.onCompletion {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnCompletion")
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

### Edit_1

If it is not possible to write something like above. Then it seems The only solution is to write using interface like below. Is there anything I need to improve or something I should pay attention to in the code below?

```
interface MyFlowListener {
    fun start()
    fun completion()
}

    var startPerformListener: MyFlowListener? = null
    fun startPerform(): Flow<Resource<Int>> = callbackFlow {
        startPerformListener = object : MyFlowListener {
            override fun start() {
                globalJob?.cancel()
                performSomething{ result ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "performSomething $result")
                    trySend(result)
                }
            }

            override fun completion() {
                globalJob?.cancel()
                channel.close()
            }
        }
        performSomething{ result ->
            Log.d(TAG, "performSomething $result")
            trySend(result)
        }


        awaitClose {
            globalJob?.cancel()
            Log.d(TAG, "startPerform awaitClose")
        }
    }
```

```
    init {
        Log.i(TAG, "Initialized")
        myRepository.startPerform()
            .onEach {
                Log.i(TAG, it.toString())
                when ( it ) {
                    is Resource.Error -> {
                        myRepository.startPerformListener?.start()
                    }
                    is Resource.Loading -> {}
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        myRepository.startPerformListener?.completion()
                    }
                }
            }.onCompletion {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnCompletion")
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

### Edit_2

EDIT:

### My queue mechanism:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
class BleDataSource  @Inject constructor(
    private val handler: Handler
) {

    private val operationQueue = ConcurrentLinkedQueue<BleOperationType>()
    private val operationLock = ReentrantLock()
    private var pendingOperation: BleOperationType? = null

    fun performConnect(device: BluetoothDevice, result: ((Resource<BleOperationResult>) -> Unit)) {
        enqueueOperation(Connect(device, result))
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun enqueueOperation(operation: BleOperationType) {
        handler.post {
            operationQueue.add(operation)
            if ( !operationLock.isLocked ) {
                doNextOperation()
            }
        }
    }


    @Synchronized
    private fun signalEndOfOperation() {
        handler.post {
            pendingOperation = null
            operationLock.unlock()
            if ( operationQueue.isNotEmpty() ) {
                doNextOperation()
            }
        }
    }


    @Synchronized
    private fun doNextOperation() {
        if ( operationLock.isLocked ) {
            Timber.i("doNextOperation already locked, returning...")
            return
        }

        val operation = operationQueue.poll() ?: run {
            Timber.v("Operation queue empty, returning...")
            return
        }
        operationLock.lock()
        pendingOperation = operation


        if ( operation is Connect ) {
            with(operation) {
                operation.result(Resource.Loading(message = "Connecting to ${device.name}"))
                bluetoothGatt = if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M ) {
                    device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback)
                } else {
                    device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)
                }
            }
        }

    }


        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            val deviceAddress = gatt.device.address
            val operation = pendingOperation
            var res: Resource<BleOperationResult> = Resource.Error(errorMessage = "Unknown Error!")

            if ( status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS ) {
                if ( newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED ) {
                    res = Resource.Loading(message = "Discovering Services")
                    gatt.discoverServices()
                } else if ( newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED ) {
                    res = Resource.Error(errorMessage = "Unexpected Disconnected")
                }
            } else {
                res = Resource.Error(errorMessage = "Error:$status encountered fro:$deviceAddress!")
            }

            if ( operation is Connect ) {
                operation.result(res)
            }
            if ( res is Resource.Error ) {
                if ( operation is Connect  ) {
                signalEndOfOperation()
                }
            }
        }


        override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
            val operation = pendingOperation
            var res: Resource<BleOperationResult> = Resource.Error(errorMessage = "Unknown Error!")

            if ( status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS ) {
              res = Resource.Success(data = BleOperationResult.ConnectionResult(profile))
                }
            } else {
                res = Resource.Error(errorMessage = "Failed to discover services...")
            }

            if ( operation is Connect ) {
                operation.result(res)
            }
            if ( pendingOperation is Connect ) {
                signalEndOfOperation()
            }
        }
```

```
abstract class BleOperationType {
    abstract val result: ((Resource<BleOperationResult>) -> Unit)
}
data class Connect(val device: BluetoothDevice,
                   override val result: ((Resource<BleOperationResult>) -> Unit)) : BleOperationType()
```

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't define the retry behavior inside the `callbackFlow` block. You can use the existing `retry` flow operator. For example:

```
init {
    Log.i(TAG, "Initialized")

    class ResourceError: Exception()

    myRepository.startPerform()
        .onEach {
            Log.i(TAG, it.toString())
            if (it is Resource.Error) {
                throw ResourceError()
            }
            //...
        }
        .retry { it is ResourceError }
        .onCompletion {
            Log.i(TAG, "OnCompletion")
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Your callback flow implementation is flawed. It can only handle there being one `globalJob` at a time, so if more than one flow is collected at once, some of them will be leaked. If any are cancelled while they're being collected in parallel, the latest one to be collected might be cancelled early.

I'm not sure if you're just trying to simulate an actual callback-based API using this global coroutine or not, because it is really hacky. If you are designing the backend yourself, there's no reason to be using `callbackFlow` in the first place. For example:

```
class MyRepository() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "___BBBMyRepository"
    }

    fun startPerform(): Flow<Resource<Int>> = flow {
        emit(Resource.Loading("Loading-1"))
        delay(2500)
        emit(Resource.Loading("Loading-2"))
        delay(2500)
        emit(Resource.Loading("Loading-3"))
        delay(2500)
        emit(Resource.Error(Exception("Try again...")))
    }
}
```

If you are trying to temporarily simulate a callback-based API using coroutines in order to test your use of `callbackFlow`, then you need to modify it so it can handle multiple "listeners" at once. Maybe something like this:

```
class MyRepository() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "___BBBMyRepository"
    }

    private fun performSomething(result: ((Resource<Int>) -> Unit)): Job {
        return GlobalScope.launch {
            result(Resource.Loading("Loading-1"))
            delay(2500)
            result(Resource.Loading("Loading-2"))
            delay(2500)
            result(Resource.Loading("Loading-3"))
            delay(2500)
            result(Resource.Error(Exception("Try again...")))
        }
    }

    fun startPerform(): Flow<Resource<Int>> = callbackFlow {
        val job = performSomething { result ->
            Log.d(TAG, "performSomething $result")
            trySend(result)
        }
        awaitClose {
            job.cancel()
            Log.d(TAG, "startPerform awaitClose")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i just wanted to simulate the sitiuation. so i wrote the code like this. Your code is working. But It runs awaitClose and runs it again. Is it possible to restarting again without running awaitclose?

Comment: So you want to avoid un-registering and re-registering your listener with the API when you restart it? This is really going to depend on how the API works. How would you tell the API to restart its work but keep using the same callback? I don't know of any APIs that would let you do this. What is the point of trying to do it this way?

Comment: Actually I have a queue structure. If the job finished successfully or the viewmodel is destroyed, I want to move on to the next operation in the queue. If I want to restart as above, I want it to try the current task again.

Comment: I couldn't show this situation in the above example, but actually I'm saving the callback (result: ((Resource<Int>) -> Unit)) in queue

Comment: I still don’t understand the reason `awaitClose` needs to be avoided. For a callback flow, it doesn’t make sense to restart it but not clean up the previous cancelled one when you restart. And it’s hard for me to visualize what your queue looks like.

Comment: actually i dont want to avoid using awaitClose. But I also need to somehow tell the callback stream to either successfully close that stream or to close the stream unsuccessfully. If the callback flow can know this stream will close successfully then 
It will move to another job of the queue where I have saved jobs. If it unsuccessful, nothing will be done about the queue and the current job will be repeated.

Comment: my queue structure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76042198/covert-lambda-result-to-flow . i ll make signalEndOfOperation() function as public and use it in awaitClose {}  
I also need to fix the structure so that the pendingOperation repeats, but that can be easily handled.

Comment: i also edited my questions to show my queue structure.